# Error when trying to play my own .wav file into a toast notification c# windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, toast

I'm trying to play a. wav file into a  toast notification. My . wav file is in the local folder of my application but unfortunately I get this exception: System.ArgumentException "Requested value 'ms-appdata:///local/archivo.wav' was not found." Anyone can help me?
here is my code that I save the file

```
 private async  void  guardarArchivo()
  {
        speak = new SpeechSynthesizer(idCliente, ClientSecret);
        speak.AudioFormat = SpeakStreamFormat.MP3;
        speak.AudioQuality = SpeakStreamQuality.MaxQuality;
        //  audio stream
        Nstream = await speak.GetSpeakStreamAsync(txtnota.Text, "es");

        inputStream = Nstream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
        DataReader datareader = new DataReader(inputStream);
        await datareader.LoadAsync((uint)Nstream.Size);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)Nstream.Size];
        datareader.ReadBytes(buffer);
        var folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;//Obtenemos el folder local donde se encuentra alojada la app
        var option = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists;//Si no existe el archivo lo crea , si existe  no pasa nada , solo sobrescribre
        //Creamos el archivo
        var archivo = await folder.CreateFileAsync("archivo.wav", option);
        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(archivo, buffer);

        }
```

here is my code that I try to create the toast notification

```
 private  void btncrearclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var toastContent = NotificationsExtensions.ToastContent.ToastContentFactory.CreateToastText01();
        toastContent.TextBodyWrap.Text =txtnota.Text;
        toastContent.Duration = ToastDuration.Long;
        //here is the error
        toastContent.Audio.Content = (ToastAudioContent)Enum.Parse(typeof(ToastAudioContent),"ms-appdata:///local/archivo.wav");
        var toast = toastContent.CreateNotification();
        ScheduledToastNotification toastnotificacion = new ScheduledToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml(), new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5)));
        var toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        toastNotifier.AddToSchedule(toastnotificacion);         

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Toast Extensions code currently does not allow you to specify your own file.

You must use one of these enums:

```
public enum ToastAudioContent
{
    Default = 0,
    Mail,
    SMS,
    IM,
    Reminder,
    LoopingCall,
    LoopingCall2,
    LoopingAlarm,
    LoopingAlarm2,
    Silent
}
```

Therefore, this line in your code:

```
toastContent.Audio.Content = (ToastAudioContent)
    Enum.Parse(typeof(ToastAudioContent),"ms-appdata:///local/archivo.wav");
```

Should be changed to use one of the enums. For example, this uses the "Mail" sound for the toast:

```
toastContent.Audio.Content = ToastAudioContent.Mail;
```